# Loopback.js/Node.js MongoDB - querying against an array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, loopbackjs

I have a structure that looks like this:

```
Model: {
  "name":"testing",
  "details":["detail1","detail2","detail10"]
}
```

How does one go about finding all instances where an above structure contains an instance of `detail2` within their details `property`?  I've tried:

```
Model.find({where:{details:{elemMatch:{"detail2"}}}},function(err,models){
    console.log(models);
    console.log(err);
});
```

and:

```
Model.find({details:"detail2"},function(err, models){
      //throws [Error: Items must be an array: "details2"]
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see (based on this comment from engineering, https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-datasource-juggler/issues/342#issuecomment-73138705), it is not possible to filter like this. You would need to get the objects and post process. In theory you could build your own remote method and do the filtering on the server so you aren't doing it server-side.